# Install SystemC 2.2.0 on Ubuntu 14.04 for executing Noxim Simulator

Tags: 14.04

**Q:** Can i install systemc 2.2.0 in Ubuntu 14.04?

Because Noxim simulator is installed with 2.2.0 version of systemC.

Answer (score 0):

Yes but by five error on install systemc-2.2.0 with many bug in the SystemC sources, because they have forgot a couple of include clauses.

To  fix it, add the following includes at the top of file

```
./src/sysc/utils/sc_utils_ids.cpp
```

If you want to soft install noxim , my be to boot down version ubuntu 
or use vmware to complete install or fix error you should Too much time away.

Iranian proverb: If really want to things, then you found it.

RFC :reference :http://www.noxim.org/